# CustomPath clips the path of image but also gives the other remaining part

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

[image]

Code of the image showing widget:

```
Container(
  color: Colors.red,
  child: ClipPath(
    clipper: ImageCropClipper(),
    child: Image.asset(
      "assets/images/amgGt.jpg",
      fit: BoxFit.contain,
      scale: 3,
    ),
  ),
),
```

Custom clipper class

```
class ImageCropClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    Path path = Path();

    path.lineTo(0, 0);
    path.lineTo(300, 0);
    path.lineTo(300, 300);
    path.lineTo(0, 300);
    path.close();

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

As seen from the above code and the image the clipper is clipping the image properly but I am also getting the left out part of the image as transparent area that is why it is taking extra width and height(which is equal to the unclipped image) and since it is transparent the background red color of parent container can be seen.

I only want the clipped area of the image and not the other unclipped part  as a transparent area because I want to use the clipped image somewhere else and the unclipped area is distorting the image dimensions.